# How to remove cells containing non numeric values from lists within list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contain sublists which contain numbers and text. 
I want to remove the text completely.

So list is like this:

```
sample_list = [['hello','there'],['1','2.0','3'],['564','text','65.976']]
```

What I've been trying is

```
list_without_text = [[item for item in sublist] for sublist in sample_list if item.isdigit()==True ]
```

But I get NameError: name 'item' is not defined.

Any ideas?

edit: All items in the lists are strings , some still with numbers, letters and/or with decimal points.

Comment: Are they all strings, just that some may be strings with only numbers.

Comment: list as variable name?

Comment: Sorry list isn't the actual variable name, just as example, I'll change.

Comment: Yes they are all strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got it wrong, the `item.isdigit()` if condition should be inside the sublist comprehension. Example -

```
list_without_text = [[item for item in sublist  if item.isdigit()==True] for sublist in sample_list]
```

But this would only work, if all the elements are strings , and you want to remove strings/floats that are not integers. This would not include numbers like `2.0` , etc.

For that you can use a function like -

```
def isnum(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

list_without_text = [[item for item in sublist  if isnum(item) ] for sublist in sample_list]
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> l = [["Hello","1"],["2.0","Bye"]]
>>> def isnum(s):
...     try:
...         float(s)
...         return True
...     except ValueError:
...         return False
...
>>> list_without_text = [[item for item in sublist  if isnum(item) ] for sublist in l]
>>> list_without_text
[['1'], ['2.0']]
```

Comment: Thanks , I forgot commas in the questions , all items within the lists are actually strings

Comment: Great , thanks a million. I'd upvote you but I'm new and I've no rep :|

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
lst= [["hello","there",],[1,2.0,3],[564,"text",65.976]]

[[ b for b in i if not isinstance(b, basestring)]for i in lst]
```

**output:**

```
[[], [1, 2.0, 3], [564, 65.976]]
```

If your list is full of `strings`

**Code:**

```
lst= [["hello","there",],["1","2.0","3"],["564","text","65.976"]]

[[ b for b in i if not b.isalpha()]for i in lst]
```

**output:**

```
[[], ['1', '2.0', '3'], ['564', '65.976']]
```

Comment: All the elements in the lists are strings , thanks though